# Modify text in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, text, swiftui

If I changed the content of `Text` in SwiftUI, the text got stretch/truncated.

For example, let's say we changed the `Text` from "World" to "SwiftUI", we got the result as shown. How do we prevent this to happened?

[image: Text got stretched in SwiftUI]

Answer (score 6):

Your code is working fine, it's probably a bug when you're previewing the app. If you actually run the app on a simulator you will see the text updating correctly. Hopefully it will be fixed in the next Xcode 11 beta releases.

---

Update: This issue was fixed with Xcode 11 beta 2.